# Linux script to run another command which requires double quotes

Tags: php, linux, command, quotes

I'm having a nightmare trying to get this to run correctly. I have done it fine using php code but the issue is with lots of files the command times out. I thought i could do this easily via ssh on the box itself but i can't get it to do what i want.

in PHP i'm doing the following:

```
$command='/usr/bin/convert "'. $LocalPDFURL . '[1]" -quality 70% "' . $LocalJPGURL . '"' ;
```

I need to search for pdf files, check if they have a .jpg with the same file name if not generate a jpg using the first page of the pdf. The above works fine in php. But in linux shell script it won't work no matter what i've tried. I've tried all sorts of combinations it just either outputs the whole thing as a string or errors as it's not passed the double quotes required to specify the full file paths (they contain spaces).

My script is this:

```
format=*.pdf
wpath=$format
for i in $wpath;
do
 if [[ "$i" == "$format" ]]
 then
    echo "No PDF Files to process!"
 else
    echo "full file name: $i"
    FILE="${i%.pdf}.jpg"
    if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE exists."
    else 
        ORIGINAL=\""${FILE%.jpg}.pdf\""
        QFILE=\""$FILE%\""
        echo "$FILE does not exist. Creating PDF Cover JPG!"
        command="/usr/bin/convert "\""$ORIGINAL"\" 1 -quality 65% $QFILE 2>&1"
        echo $command
    fi

 fi
done
```

I just want to build the command and execute it.

The php command output looks like this...

```
"/usr/bin/convert "/home/test/1.pdf" 1 -quality 65% "/home/test/1.jpg" 2>&1"
```

and runs fine.

I've tried single quotes, double quotes escaping them etc. Please someone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my advice is the following:

1. create a function in bash that does what you want (ie: given a pdf file, check if the corresponding jpg file exists, if not convert it)
2. apply the function to all your pdf files

```sh
maybe_convert(){
  ! [ -f "${1%.*}.jpg" ] && echo "/usr/bin/convert \"$1\" 1 -quality 65% \"${1%.*}.jpg\"" || echo $1 exists
}
export -f maybe_convert
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" | xargs -I{} bash -c "maybe_convert \"{}\""
```

The snippet above works for the following file structure (assuming thet you have saved the snippet in a file named `convert_image.sh`):

```sh
$ ls testdir/
'file 1.jpg'  'file 1.pdf'  'file 2.pdf'  'file 3.pdf'
$ bash convert_image.sh
/usr/bin/convert "./testdir/file 3.pdf" 1 -quality 65% "./testdir/file 3.jpg"
/usr/bin/convert "./testdir/file 2.pdf" 1 -quality 65% "./testdir/file 2.jpg"
./testdir/file 1.pdf exists
```

Comment: Thanks. At the moment using my script above I get all of the files. I can create the function within the script but how do i call it with the $ORIGINAL variable i'm using that contains the full pdf file name? I've tried using your code but I can't get it to work. I also tried just using your code separately it just says "no such file or directory".

Comment: I've managed to add the function and call it correctly. However the double quotes are not working inside the function. The files names have spaces in them so the output to the convert program needs to be with double quotes surrounding it. It's outputting the command now but it's truncating it at the first space in the filename. i.e. "my file name 1" is being output as "my". I have tried to encase the filename in double quotes in my $QFILE as above neither of these work unfortunately.

Comment: Try with quotes around the curly braces in the last line (like I updated the answer)

Comment: No it still doesn't work. The input file name is truncated at the first space. "my file name1" is output as "my" still.

Comment: Have you also added the quotes around the first occurence of the filename variable (i.e. in `[ -f "${1%.*}.jpg" ]`)? I forgot to mention it in my previous comment

Comment: I've tried it with quotes and without using QFILE and FILE neither works.

Comment: I don't get it, there is no `QFILE` nor `FILE` in the snippet that I provided. Please try with the snippet from my answer without adding stuff to it. Also, if there is an error message, mention here what it says

Comment: I added the function to the code and have tried it with and without quotes on the original file name. The snippet you've provided doesn't run on its own. There is no error returned nothing happens running the snippedt from the shell. When running the code in script it simply doesn't pass the full file name as explained it stops at the first space in the file name which causes the command to fail as the file is not found.

Comment: the `find` command finds all the files that ends with `.pdf`. The `xargs` command applies the function to each file separately (i.e. it replaces the loop). Try to apply the function to one file, if it does not work, modify it so that it works for one file. I don't know what your filestructure looks like, nor even how the files are named. If you want help, you need to give more information...

Comment: It runs fine however the files are named with spaces in them, the issue is that the filename needs to be passed to the convert program enclosed in double quotes. At the moment it is not doing this so the file path passed to the convert program is "my" rather than "my file 1,pdf". I have a number of files in the directory at the moment just 4 in a test dir but i wanted to use the shell to do the covert as i have 1000s of files and it times out the web process (which runs absolutely fine apart from the timeouts). At present i'm having to run the php code multiple times which is frustrating.

Comment: I have added an example in my answer and I showed what the code outputs. It works for me, even with filenames containing spaces. If it does not work for you and you cannot give me a concrete example of a filename that fails, I cannot do anything for you.

Comment: Thank you. I've got it running now. How do i execute the commands rather than just echo them?

Comment: remove `echo` in front of the command, remove the quotes around the command, and unescape the quotes inside. Also, If you are done with this issue, please close it by accepting the answer

Comment: I've marked as answer accepted. Thank you very much for your help with this! One final thing if you don't mind. How do i deal with single quotes inside filenames? I get this for the odd few "xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option" many thanks again.

Comment: Single quotes in names on linux are handled in the same way as spaces and other special characters: you either need to escape them or you enclose them in double quotes